# Interactive world map on a MVC 3 EF model first project

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to do this with MVC 3 EF Model first

I want to make a interactive world map webapp where users can click on red dots and get a brief description of the red dot and then users should be able to click inside the popup and get more detailed information like pictures and detailed text etc.

I will also need to create it in a way that me as webmaster can create these red dots and type the information and create pictures.

Example:

Sweden have 2 red dots one in Stockholm and one in Gothenburg.

Red dot in Stockholm is about a Rock event, gothenburgs red dot is about a techno festival.

Red dots need to also be located on the street where it takes place.

What I am looking for is a easy way to create this functionality with MVC 3 EF model first.

Maby any tools, tutorials, Perhaps libraries or open-source

Any kind of help is appreciated so I can take my first step into this :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Google Maps API, this would solve your world map problem and allow you to place markers as well as any additional marker information that you might want to make available.

https://developers.google.com/maps/visualize
https://developers.google.com/maps/

Your question is very generic so its hard to "answer" as such however, I was looking at the google maps API a few weeks ago and managed to get soemthing up and running pretty quickly.

Your "Model First" approach doesnt really effect my answer as however you slice the cake is completely up to you however I would seriously consider taking a long hard look at the functionality that google give you right out of the box for building apps very similar to the one you describe!

Comment: I think I will do it with google maps API v3 but I still wonder if there is somekind of library so I can use C# but output code is javascript?